# Difference between the two ways object methods can reference object properties

Tags: javascript, object, this

There are two ways of having object methods reference object properties:

```js
let i = {a: 'apple', b: function(){return i.a}}
let j = {a: 'apple', b: function(){return this.a}}

console.log(i.b())  // apple
console.log(j.b())  // apple
```

What are the pros/cons of these two approaches to referencing object properties??

Comment: `i` always refers to `i`. `this` may vary.

Comment: Yes, but what are the pros/cons of the two approaches of referencing the object properties?

Comment: AFAIK, the first method is only valid if you have access to i, while the second would also work if j itself is not available but the pointer it represents is stored in another variable.

Comment: Might you reassign `i`? Might you call the function in a way that `this` differs? It’s hard to boil this down to “pros” or “cons”, one can only say what it does and you decide what you want.

Comment: @kev `i` will always stay available here as a closed over variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They mean different things. The first one returns the `a` property of some variable `i` that's in scope. The fact that the object is also named `i` means it works as expected. But that's not guaranteed. For example:

```js
let i = {a: 'apple', b: function(){return i.a}}
let j = i
i = {a: "potato"}

console.log(j.b()) // apple or potato?
```

So long as you expect the function to look into the scope, find an `i` and return it's `a` prop, then this works as expected. But it doesn't mean, return the `a` prop of the object in this function.

Then second *does* mean that so long as it's called with `i.b()`, but `this` doesn't refer to the object where the function was defined — it's value is determined the context of the function call. For example

```js
let i = {a: 'apple', b: function(){return this.a}}
let j = {a: 'potato'}
j.b = i.b

console.log(j.b()) // apple or potato
```

One isn't *better* than the other, they are different ideas and can serve different function.

Comment: Great examples!

Answer (score 2):

Actually, these functions are not doing the same thing.

Let's consider the first one.

```
let i = {a: 'apple', b: function(){return i.a}}
```

You define a function `function(){return i.a}` which will return a value from object i. Whenever or wherever its called, it will return the value from object i.
It is totally independent of scope. You can't reuse this function as a method of a prototype. Because `i` is always `i`. It may be useful if you are not using arrow functions to secure your call context.

On the other hand, the other function is different.

```
let j = {a: 'apple', b: function(){return this.a}}
```

You are using `this` so it will access to property a based on its context.

---

Making everything more clear with an example.
Let's say that I have a sheep and dog objects with a property `sound`.

```
const dog = {
   sound: 'woof-woof'
};

const sheep = {
   sound: 'Meaeeeeee'
};
```

Now I am defining a function `makeSound`

```
function makeSound {
   alert(this.sound)
}
```

Now I want to use `makeSound` for both animals. All I have to do is calling this function by giving it a context.

```
makeSound.call(sheep) // -> Meaeeeeee
makeSound.call(dog) // -> woof-woof
```

`this` helped me to reuse this function for the different type of objects. This is where prototypal inheritance came from.

Comment: `this` is not *scope*, it’s *context*. Variables have scope, but `this` isn’t a traditional variable.

Comment: @deceze You are right, fixed my mistake. Thank you.